# Using Spearman's rho to analyse results of an experiment

Tags: correlation, experiment-design, spearman-rho

I have just gathered some data for an experiment I am doing for my research. There are two groups in my experiment. Each of them is shown a different prompt, and subsequently asked two questions. The first question has a yes'no answer, the second a yes/perhaps/no answer. I am trying to see if seeing Prompt #1 can induce people to choose 'Yes' in the follow-up questions.

I am working in SPSS. The data that I have includes: the size of both groups, and the number of respondents in each group who picked each response. Prompt 1 is coded as 1.00, Prompt 2 is coded as 0. Similarly, Yes is coded as 1.00 and No is coded as 0.00. I thought about using Spearman's rho to look for a correlation between each prompt and people's responses. Is this reasonable?

My apologies if this is a stupid question, but I have pretty much had to 'learn' stats overnight, so I could really use some help.

Answer (score 1):

Spearman's rho is note a good idea here, it is more for looking at the correlation of two continuous variables.

Assuming that assignment to the different prompts was done in a randomized manner, your example would seem like a classic case for using logistic regression (or if there is no further things to be taken into account Fisher's exact test, which is essentially exact conditional logistic regression). Logistic regression provides you both an effect measure (the odds ratio), measures of uncertainty around the effect measure (e.g. standard error, confidence interval) and a hypothesis test.

If the assignment was not randomized (e.g. by self-selection), things become much more complicated and you may have to look e.g. into propensity score methods (e.g. logistic regression stratified by deciles of propensity scores).

Comment: Thank you, logistic regression looks promising! However, all the examples which I have managed to find so far have the dichotomous variable as the dependent variable, and some scale variable as the IV. I am not sure how to use logistic regression with both variables being dichotomous -- do you have any good resources to recommend? Sorry if the question is stupid, but I pretty much have had to learn stats overnight so I am still a bit clueless.

Comment: Probably any clinical trial that analyses a yes/no (reponse/non-response, event/no-event) outcome for treatment (1=yes/active) versus a control (0=0/control) using logistic regression does this. For examples, e.g. google.scholar for +"randomized clinical trial" +"logistic regression". I also find plenty of promising looking material when google.scholar-ing for allintitle:+"logistic regression" +primer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Spearman's rho as it assumes ordinality, that is, you can order your data in increasing order. Given that you converted your data to 0/1 you could do it, but it doesn't really make sense, as yes in not "more" than no.

To me this sounds like data that would be best analysed with a McNemar test given that the data is paired. You can then look at the contingency table to identify the direction of the effect. Read more on a McNemar test [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar's_test)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. To my understanding thogh McNemar's would only work if the same people were shown the two prompts and then asked the questions. However, I am showing the two prompts to two completely different groups, so I am not sure if the McNemar tes would work. Or am I just misinterpreting things?

Comment: Ow, I misunderstood your question then. As you said that you wanted to find out if showing prompt 1 induces them choose yes in a follow up question, I assumed they were the same people. How would you conclude that if it's different people that you show it to? In any case if it's different groups of people then you can use a Chi-square test of independence (or Fisher's test depending if your cell count is low). They work more or less in the same way. Or if you want to control for more factors you can use logistic regression as Björn suggests (works fine with binary IVs as well)